# Project with custom indexes fails on package build command

Tags: managed-package, scratch-org, second-generation-packaging, custom-index

Writing an app to publish on the AppExchange, and this app contains some text fields that have a uniqueness constraint on them. As per the Salesforce documentation, when that constraint is applied the platform creates automatically a custom index for it.

This custom index now has its own metadata file, ending with `.indx-meta.xml`. Those are retrieved in the project and can be versioned.

The problem is that when building a new package version, I get an obscure error from the Salesforce server:

```
CustomObject__c.CustomIndexField__c: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 57207XXXX-XXXXX (172149XXXX)
```

*Note: error id is redacted in the above sample.*

Is this new metadata type not usable, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of December 1st of 2022 this is an issue, but might get fixed in the future. The documentation on custom indexes is, apparently, a work in progress. Meanwhile, the workaround is to ignore the index files using the `.forceignore` file, then you are still able to deploy to the scratch org and generate a package version.